# How to replace subscribe() in RBatchReactive.execute().subscribe()

Tags: java, redis, project-reactor, flux

Given below is a piece of Java Micronaut code I am using for removing entries from redis. But this code does not remove entries from redis. If I use `batch.execute().subscribe();` then it is working, but I do not want to use subcribe(), so is there any solution for that?

```
private Mono<Void> removeFromRedis(String[] entries) {
    var batch = redis.createBatch();
    batch.getMap("map_name").fastRemove(entries);
    batch.execute(); //if I use batch.execute().subscribe(); here then it will work
    return Mono.empty();
}
```